# accessing values structure within structure?

Tags: c, structure

I have declared a typedef structure and in another typedef structure i am using the first typedef .. but how can i access the value of first type def structure.. like for eg...

```
typedef struct num
{
        uint32_t number1;
        uint32_t number2;    
}d1;

typedef struct Employee
{
       char ename[20];
       int ssn;
       float salary;
       d1 number;
}emp1;
```

If I use

```
printf("value of number1: %" PRIu32 "\n",emp1.number.number1);
```

I don't get expected value and if I type

```
printf("value of number: %" PRIu64 "\n",emp1.number);
```

then even i dont get expected value but i get warning that

> warning: format `%lu` expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘d1’ [-Wformat]

Can anyone help me with this ?

Is there any format specifier for `typedef` structure?

Comment: What is the value that you are expecting then? The first `printf` line looks fine.

Comment: *I don't get expected value* - It's probably because whatever `emp1` is wasn't given that value, but how would we know?

Comment: "for eg"? "four eggs"?

Comment: Is there any reason you take a different identifier for tag and typedef-name?

Comment: @KerrekSB, Can't say I've ever seen the tautology at the beginning.

Comment: "For eg" as an abbreviation of "for example", which is sometimes written as "e.g." with the example following?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, [Shouldn't, but can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b62c0da8668c80c).

Comment: @chris My mistake. It can't be done within the same scope... I was testing the idea with a global typedef and global variable. You're right when you say naming a variable the same as a typedef shouldn't be done in my opinion...

Comment: @chris: redundant, not tautological :-S Much like in the code, the OP is just guessing at things that are sort of words and hoping that a sentence comes out.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Oh wow, my bad. Never again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an object of emp1 inside your main, and give it a value like below and it should be ok

```
emp1 emp;
emp.number.number1=3;
//printf then with emp.number.number1 ;)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the value "number1" like

```
emp1.number.number1
```

but here "emp" data type defined by you. So to access "number1" from other struct, first ou have to create object of the second struct. Like

```
emp1 obj;
```

and then access "number1" from second struct like

```
obj.number.number1
```

Comment: If it was used as the data type, the code would not compile, yet the OP says [it runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b62c0da8668c80c).

Comment: Actually, my bad. The question could totally be interpreted as the code not compiling. That's just... meh.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've provided, not a single variable is being declared. There are only two structure definitions there (`num` and `Employee`), and then two type definitions associated with them (`d1` and `emp1`).

If you were to attempt compiling a code as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct num {
    uint32_t number1;
    uint32_t number2;
} d1;

typedef struct Employee {
    char ename[20];
    int ssn;
    float salary;
    d1 number;
} emp1;

int main( ) {
    printf( "value of number1: %" PRIu32 "\n", emp1.number.number1 );
    return 0;
}
```

You'd receive an error, indicating that there is no variable such as `emp1` available.

First, I'll try to briefly explain what `typedef` does: It defines new a new type, or several new types; for an already defined type you desire. The syntax is as follows:

```
typedef definedtype newtype1[, newtype2, ... ];
```

One particular use of it is that it allows you to create a new variable with that `newtype1` you've defined, like for example:

```
emp1    empvariable1;
// equivalent to struct Employee empvariable1;
```

So, if you were hoping to have a variable of your structure and call it `emp1`, you should change the name of the new type you've defined; then also declare a variable of that type with the name `emp1`, also preferably initialize it as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct num {
    uint32_t number1;
    uint32_t number2;
} d1;

typedef struct Employee {
    char ename[20];
    int ssn;
    float salary;
    d1 number;
} emp;  // removed "1"

int main( ) {
    emp emp1 = {
        "ThoAppelsin",
        1337,
        123456789.0,
        {
            100,
            200
        }
    };

    printf( "value of number1: %" PRIu32 "\n", emp1.number.number1 );
    return 0;
}
```

Now it prints `100`, hopefully as you'd expect it to, as I do.